# Submitting a Form to insert SQL with ajax

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax

This is my first attempt to use ajax to submit a form so I'm unsure where I am going wrong.

I have a pop up that shows on users first visit every day, it has a button to log attendance which basically will insert the time stamp of submit along with the user etc, I have tested the PHP manually by taking it out of an isset and just hitting the page and it is inserting, but when I try to use ajax it isn't, I have watched the network in developer tools, and its hitting the page when clicked but isn't inserting the data.

This is my modal:

```
<form method="post" data-remote="true">
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Morning, <?php echo $user['userName']; ?>.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php $today = date("D M j"); ?>
                <h4>Are you working today <?php echo $today; ?>?</h4>
                <p>By clicking 'Log My Attendance' you are confirming that you are working today.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="log-attendance" type="buttom" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Log My Attendance</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#log-attendance', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'log-attendance.php',
            success: function() {
              "Attendance Log success"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $val1 = "test";
    $val2 = "test";
    $val3 = "test";
    $val4 = "test";
    $val5 = "test";
    $val6 = "test";

    $query = "INSERT INTO po_users (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6) 
            VALUES ('$val1', '$val2','$val3', '$val4', '$val5', '$val6')";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($sapconn2, $query);
    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
}
?>
```

Comment: you miss the data part in the ajax function. You are not posting anything to the php page

Comment: What would i submit with data, would it be the form name?

Comment: what are these `$val` in ur php for? Please post the real data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check this**

```
    <form method="post" data-remote="true" id="myform">
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Morning, <?php echo $user['userName']; ?>.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php $today = date("D M j"); ?>
                    <h4>Are you working today <?php echo $today; ?>?</h4>
                    <p>By clicking 'Log My Attendance' you are confirming that you are working today.</p>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="log-attendance" type="buttom" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Log My Attendance</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>

/* On form submit */   
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //var formdata = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'log-attendance.php',
            method : 'POST',
            success : function(res)
            {
                alert(res);
            }
    });
    });

    });



/* on  button click */

    $(function() {
        $('#log-attendance').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //var formdata = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'log-attendance.php',
            method : 'POST',
            success : function(res)
            {
                alert(res);
            }
    });
    });

    });
</script>
```

> log-attendance.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username"; /* Your username */
$password = "password"; /* Your password */
$dbname = "myDB";   /* Your dbname */

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$val1 = "test";
$val2 = "test";
$val3 = "test";
$val4 = "test";
$val5 = "test";
$val6 = "test";

$query = "INSERT INTO po_users (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6) 
            VALUES ('".$val1."', '".$val2."','".$val3."', '".$val4."', '".$val5."', '".$val6."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Tried this, i am getting the exact same result, ajax fires the url but nothing happens

Comment: Try above code now ...

Comment: This works but like i said its not wrapped in an isset, so going forward i cant amend this to add other buttons in the future

Comment: Check above code now i mention both events 1.On submit form 2. On click button .

Comment: @PHPNewbie why do you need isset? u using ajax to submi therefore ajax have the on submit function. therefore on your php you won't need to check if the button is clicked

Comment: Yes  have just realised that i was over complicating it in my head, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: welcome@PHPNewbie.. :)